# Why does 2 Try/Catch blocks freeze the application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, try-catch

I am writing a simple application that take input from 2 textboxes as numerator and denominator, and then passes them to a `Reduce()` method.

I need to convert the textbox strings to integers, but i don't want it to stop the program if a user accidentally types a non-numeric key, so I put the assignments inside of Try...Catch statements in order to prevent that from happening.

However, when i type in letters into the 2 textboxes and press the button, the window just freezes and goes all screwy. Could anyone explain what is going on?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnReduce_Click(ByVal sender As Object, 
          ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnReduce.Click
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    Try
        n = Val(txtNum.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Please enter a numeric numerator", , "ERROR")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    Try
        d = Val(txtDenom.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Please enter a numeric denominator", , "ERROR")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    Reduce(n, d)
    Dim reduced As String = n.ToString + "/" + d.ToString
    lblDisplay.Text = "The reduced fraction is " + reduced
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) You have been a big help to me these past couple of months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than a `Try/Catch` or `Val` use `Integer.TryParse` (or other type).  The problem is that `Val` wont throw an exception if it is bad.  It will return the value for any leading numerals:

```
n = Val("abc")          ' == 0.0
n = Val("1a2b3c")       ' == 1.0
```

It also always returns a `Double`, so the following:

```
Dim n As Integer
n = Val(txtNum.Text)
```

...is invalid code under `Option Strict` - you are trying to assign a Double to an integer.

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim d As Integer

' if it can parse a value, it will be stored in n
If Integer.TryParse(txtNum.Text, n) = False Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a numeric numerator", , "ERROR")
    Exit Sub
End If

If Integer.TryParse(txtDenom.Text, d) = False Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a numeric numerator", , "ERROR")
    Exit Sub
End If

Reduce(n, d)
...
```

One of the benefits to `*.TryParse()` is that it *avoids* exceptions by returning a `Boolean`.  Exceptions are not for flow control or data validation, which is how your code is trying to use them.

In general it is best to avoid those legacy VB functions like `Val` and `Mid` in favor of the NET counterparts which are usually more powerful and more flexible with better typing.

Also, turn on `Option Strict` - it will convert many runtime errors and spooky bugs into compiler errors with the line/problem pointed out.  For example, it is probably not actually stuck in that method, but later when using bad values somewhere.